# Boot error when using a USB

Tags: 12.04, installation, 10.04, iso, unetbootin

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using a USB stick. I'm currently using ubuntu 10.04.
I have a 12.04 LTS `.iso` and tried to make a bootable stick using Startup Disk Creator.  The process finishes and when I try to boot a "boot error" message is displayed.

I don't know how to use Unetbootin. My MD5 checksum is ok. I have a C2D 2.66, 2 GB RAM, 320 GB HDD.

Comment: When you used Startup Disk Creator, did you follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)? What was the full and exact text of the "boot error" error message? (Was it really just "boot error"? What happened before that error message occurred? Were there any other messages?) Also, you said the `.iso` passed the [MD5 test](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), but what about ["Check disc for defects"](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) from the USB flash drive when booting it (if you can).

Comment: I'm seeing this, and I really do just get `Loading Operating System ...` then `Boot error` and nothing else.  Not very helpful.

Comment: Sad that noone has helped fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Unetbootin. Try Universal USB Installer. It's easier and it gives you more options of distributions. Here goes the link:

[Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: Universal USB Installer is nice, but it only works on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Using UNETBOOTIN is very easy. Just install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Then run it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `unetbootin`.

Enter your password and then you'll see the main menu. Tick the second radio button (Disk image) and browse to the ISO file of the distribution you want to make the live disk of. Make sure the pendrive is empty, or else format it to FAT through Disk Utility. Mount it again if you format it, and it'll be detected by UNETBOOTIN. Then the wizard will do the work and you'll have you disk ready.

But remember, there is  difference. Unetbootin creates a live version of the distro, which is primarily used to test it in live mode (without installing) or for installation of the distro to a system. On the other hand, Startup Disk creator makes your usb stick ready as a distro itself, so that you can use it as a portable OS.

Since you say that your system is showing boot error, I suggest you reset your BIOS and set it to boot again from USB drives. Besides, you should format your drive once, before creating the startup disk. Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't `unetbootin` need to be run as `root`? If you're running it manually from the Alt+F2 box, don't you need to run `gksu unetbootin` (or `gksudo unetbootin`, or `kdesudo unetbootin` on Kubuntu, or `sudo unetbootin`)?

Comment: Also, it's not correct to say that Unetbootin makes a live USB but Startup Disk Creator makes a portable OS. Normally Startup Disk Creator will create a live USB ([official Ubuntu installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) tell you to use Startup Disk Creator for this purpose); it can also be used to create a live USB with a persistent area. It doesn't create a fully persistent portable OS; for that, you have to run the installer and install on the USB flash drive.

Comment: @qwwee is trying to install Ubuntu using a USB stick. Therefore, he may want to use unetbootin on Windowsin which case, he doesn't need root.

Comment: That was probably worth a try, but it didn't fix a similar problem for me.